# what should i be careful when sending email with PHP so it does not goes in spam(especialy Yahoo Mail)

Tags: php, email, spam, swiftmailer

i am building a web that sends email for reseting password, verifying email and newsletter.

what i want to know what should i do it does not go into spam?

now i am looking in SwiftMailer documentation to see how it can help me

thanks in advance

Comment: please search this site for "[email] [php] [spam]", this question is asked much too much.

Answer (score 1):

Using a well tested library for composing the e-mail (like SwiftMailer) is a first step. It ensures that the mail is not classified as spam solely because of non-adherence to the relevant RFCs. Additionaly, SpamAssassin provides [Some Tips for Legitimate Senders to Avoid False Positives](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/AvoidingFpsForSenders).